# Why React use createFiber instead of new FiberNode?

Tags: reactjs

I noticed that React wraps the `FiberNode` constructor in `createFiber` function.

```js
const createFiber = function(
    tag: WorkTag,
    pendingProps: mixed,
    key: null | string,
    mode: TypeOfMode,
): Fiber {
    // $FlowFixMe: the shapes are exact here but Flow doesn't like constructors
    return new FiberNode(tag, pendingProps, key, mode);
};
```

Why should React do this? Can't we just call `new FiberNode(tag, pendingprops, key, mode)` instead of calling `createFiber`? What they do are the same and `new FiberNode(tag, pendingprops, key, mode)` is more straightforward.